# Crash with error "No more room to grow table"

Tags: macos, memory, crash, kernel-panic

For the past week or so my computer has been crashing at least once a day with the same error.

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8018318b7f): "No more room to grow table: 0x0xffffff8018ab3e00 size:262142, used:262141, requested elem:1"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.60.10/osfmk/kern/waitq.c:594
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff802e83bd60 : 0xffffff80182dab52
0xffffff802e83bde0 : 0xffffff8018318b7f
0xffffff802e83be60 : 0xffffff8018316122
0xffffff802e83be70 : 0xffffff80182d43ac
0xffffff802e83bee0 : 0xffffff80182d1bb8
0xffffff802e83bf10 : 0xffffff80183b8eca
0xffffff802e83bfb0 : 0xffffff80183ecd86

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Google Chrome He

Mac OS version:
15G31

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 23 18:25:34 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: B5AA8E3E-65B6-3D0E-867B-8DCCF81E536C
Kernel slide:     0x0000000018000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8018200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8018100000
System model name: MacBookPro11,5 (Mac-06F11F11946D27C5)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 12138432578219
```

I've wiped the drive and re-installed El Capitan but I'm still getting the same issue.

I use this machine for software development, so there's a good amount of CPU and memory intense operations, a couple virtual environments, and I run Chrome Canary, Chromium, and Chrome which I know are big hogs as far as browsers go.  However, when running low on memory before I recall there being a dialog window that "Your system is low on memory" and I was able to close programs before a crash.

What would be causing this issue?  Hardware failure?  Memory leak in a program?

I notice that last process name is `Google Chrome He` so maybe it's just time I switch browsers...

Comment: It seems to be the Google Chrome Helper process.  Have you tried removing Chrome to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: What version of Chrome you have? I have the same problem and mine is `62.0.3192.0 dev`

Comment: I run Chrome `60.0.3112.101 (Official Build) (64-bit)`, Chromium `62.0.3194.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit)`, and Chrome Canary `62.0.3194.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)`.  I've switched to Safari, Firefox, and Opera and haven't had any crashes, so I think it's just an issue with Chrome's software, though I haven't narrowed down which one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems it's a Google Chrome issue and the team is working on a fix.

Check [this issue](http://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=756102).

Comment: Well I'm relieved it doesn't appear to be an issue with my machine, then.  I've stopped using Chrome and for the past few days haven't had any crashes, so definitely the culprit.

Comment: I have the same problem in Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit). I thought it was due to graphical acceleration, and turned that all off, but it didn't help.

Comment: A few years later, I'm hitting this same issue and I'm not using Chrome. It's installed but not running – doesn't even have a helper running.