# 2013 Mac Pro keeps crashing, but only during night

Tags: crash, mac-pro

Sometimes with no apps running in the background it still shuts down. All RAM sticks are working fine. The thing I'm thinking is the "**BSD process name corresponding to current thread: **profiles**

```
Anonymous UUID:       2F7369A8-FC38-E5B5-97C5-F588593691E7

Sun Jun  2 03:33:57 2019

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 14 caller 0xffffff8015c7ee2c): "No more room to grow table: 0x0xffffff8016641ee0 size:262142, used:262141, requested elem:1"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4570.71.22/osfmk/kern/ltable.c:461
Backtrace (CPU 14), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa78d433930 : 0xffffff8015c6e1c6 
0xffffffa78d433980 : 0xffffff8015d96a74 
0xffffffa78d4339c0 : 0xffffff8015d88d44 
0xffffffa78d433a30 : 0xffffff8015c201e0 
0xffffffa78d433a50 : 0xffffff8015c6dc3c 
0xffffffa78d433b80 : 0xffffff8015c6d9fc 
0xffffffa78d433be0 : 0xffffff8015c7ee2c 
0xffffffa78d433c70 : 0xffffff8015cb5764 
0xffffffa78d433c90 : 0xffffff8015c594cd 
0xffffffa78d433ce0 : 0xffffff80161040df 
0xffffffa78d433d90 : 0xffffff8016103030 
0xffffffa78d433ee0 : 0xffffff80161056c5 
0xffffffa78d433f40 : 0xffffff8016204248 
0xffffffa78d433fa0 : 0xffffff8015c209c6 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: profiles

Mac OS version:
17G5019

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Dec 20 21:47:19 PST 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.22~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4A5298BF-709E-37DF-B7F0-4298065CC266
Kernel slide:     0x0000000015a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8015c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8015b00000
System model name: MacPro6,1 (Mac-F60DEB81FF30ACF6)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 141280868634335
last loaded kext at 247482979550: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f96e01000, size 69632)
loaded kexts:
com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.snowleopard 5.9.1
com.Sonarworks.driver.Sonarworks    1.8.11
com.evoluent.driver.VerticalMouseDriver 1.3.0f1
com.promise.r2p.icon    1.0.7
com.softraid.driver.SoftRAID    5.7.5
com.owc.driver.SCSI-Device  1.1.0b16
com.owc.driver.SATA-Command 8.1.0b16
com.promise.driver.stex 6.2.9
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.2.3
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.37
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.5
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.6.8
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000   1.6.8
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.20.14
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.20.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   281.52
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.7f12
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.kext.AMD7000Controller    1.6.8
com.apple.driver.AppleMGPUPowerControl  3.20.14
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter  107
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 135
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTopCaseDriver  135
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   6.0.7f12
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  404.30.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBStorageCoexistentDriver    439.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.50.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelI210Ethernet 2.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.9
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.51.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1241.31.1a9
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.50.2
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 220.50.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   220.50.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4030HWLibs 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    378.26
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices 1.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 683.1
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   680.15
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 281.52
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   211.15
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.20.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.6.8
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.20.14
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.20.14
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   519.21
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.9
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    519.21
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 281.52
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 135
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.7f12
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    1614.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   205.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  1614.1
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    1614.11
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.7f12
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.7f12
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.7f12
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.7f12
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  312.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOATAFamily 2.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter   2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   4.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIParallelFamily    3.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.7.9
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.40.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.60.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.70.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    680.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacPro6,1, BootROM 127.0.0.0.0, 8 processors, 8-Core Intel Xeon E5, 3 GHz, 64 GB, SMC 2.20f18
Graphics: AMD FirePro D500, AMD FirePro D500, PCIe
Graphics: AMD FirePro D500, AMD FirePro D500, PCIe
Memory Module: DIMM2, 32 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1066 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D3339334234473730444D302D5948392020
Memory Module: DIMM3, 32 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1066 MHz, 0x802C, 0x37324B535A5334473732505A2D3147344532
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x135), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.31.1a9)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.7f12, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Studio La Nostalgia, Ethernet, en0
PCI Card: AMD FirePro D500, Display Controller, Slot-1
PCI Card: AMD FirePro D500, Display Controller, Slot-2
PCI Card: pci1b21,612, AHCI Controller, Thunderbolt@238,0,0
PCI Card: pci105a,8760, RAID Controller, Thunderbolt@182,0,0
PCI Card: pci1b21,612, AHCI Controller, Thunderbolt@79,0,0
PCI Card: pci1b21,612, AHCI Controller, Thunderbolt@107,0,0
PCI Card: pci1b21,612, AHCI Controller, Thunderbolt@80,0,0
PCI Card: pci1b21,612, AHCI Controller, Thunderbolt@105,0,0
PCI Card: pci1b21,612, AHCI Controller, Thunderbolt@78,0,0
PCI Card: pci1b73,1100, USB eXtensible Host Controller, Thunderbolt@160,0,0
PCI Card: pci1b21,612, AHCI Controller, Thunderbolt@106,0,0
PCI Card: pci1b21,612, AHCI Controller, Thunderbolt@77,0,0
PCI Card: ethernet, Ethernet Controller, Thunderbolt@159,0,0
PCI Card: pci1b21,612, AHCI Controller, Thunderbolt@104,0,0
PCI Card: pci1b73,1100, USB eXtensible Host Controller, Thunderbolt@158,0,0
PCI Card: pci11c1,5901, IEEE 1394 Open HCI, Thunderbolt@157,0,0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256F, 251 GB
Serial ATA Device: ST3000DM008-2DM166, 3 TB
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: HGST HTS721010A9E630, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: HGST HTS721010A9E630, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: HGST HTS721010A9E630, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: HGST HTS721010A9E630, 1 TB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: My Passport 259F
USB Device: Drive Dock
USB Device: Drive Dock
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
USB Device: 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
USB Device: Magic Trackpad 2
USB Device: iLok
USB Device: eLicenser
USB Device: iLok
USB Device: Evoluent VerticalMouse 4
USB Device: USB audio CODEC
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: Quartet
USB Device: USB MIDI LMK2V2
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac Pro, Apple Inc., 19.2
Thunderbolt Device: ThunderBay 4, Other World Computing, 1, 24.2
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac Pro, Apple Inc., 19.2
Thunderbolt Device: ThunderBay 4 mini, Other World Computing, 1, 25.1
Thunderbolt Device: Thunderbolt 2 Dock, Other World Computing, Inc., 3, 25.1
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac Pro, Apple Inc., 19.2
Thunderbolt Device: Pegasus2-R, Promise Technology, Inc., 1, 19.2
Thunderbolt Device: d2, LaCie, 3, 7.4
```

Comment: better we have the text than a picture of it. First thing to do in any panic scenario is eliminate 3rd party kexts, of which I can see quite a few. [paste the panic text, drag/select it all & hit ctrl/k which will format it nicely for markdown.]

Comment: I'm brand new to this site. Can't find anywhere to "edit" my question/post.

Comment: Should be at the bottom of the question, or click this [edit]

Comment: I'd be worried about the pace - is that from Altiverb?

Comment: I just updated the crash report to show the FULL REPORT.  @Tetsujin what pace are you referring to?

Comment: Also, in the BSD line at the top, it says profiles as the source.   Does that mean that is causing the restarting to happen?

Comment: Google says that might be a Chrome panic. The ancient paceap might be a red herring  - `com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.snowleopard 5.9.1`

Comment: Meaning what? I should reinstall Chrome? Because I'm running the latest Chrome version.

Comment: you can find some help here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296007/crash-with-error-no-more-room-to-grow-table/296179

Comment: Correct. I had read that thread before posting, but figured it wasn't a Chrome issue since I'm running the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Will try uninstalling Chrome and see if the situation continues.

Comment: @user334536 take in count that sometimes those fix are related to specific Mac models So try reinstalling or change installed version so you can track the issue and check if it's about chrome's version.

Comment: @historystamp I'm on 10.13.6 High Sierra. How do I go about deleting/updating it? Thanks!

Comment: @user334536 try with appZapper! it will delete all preferences and small files that are related to chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try running in safe mode. See if problem persists. Try a safe boot. Shutdown your machine. Hold down the shift key. Poweron. The boot up will take longer than normal because the filesystem on the startup drive is being checked and repaired as needed. All about safe mode including what features and apps safe boot leaves out. Safe boot uses a software driver instead of using your machines video hardware.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455

I'm suspicious about com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.snowleopard 5.9.1 for two reason.  I assume you are running a more recent version of macOS. Secondly, it seems to be part of some anti-virus app.  Fyi: Anti-virus apps are a frequent cause of macOS problems.  How to uninstall:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1640428

Run etrecheck and post results back here.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/etrecheck/id1423715984?mt=12

Comment: I'm more inclined to think paceap is music-related, as there's an iLok key & eLicenser listed [Pace & Steinberg respectively] as well as Sonarworks.